# Error in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, : polygon edge not found

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to run [this awesome markdown](https://github.com/Z3tt/OutlierConf2021/blob/main/R/OutlierConf2021_ggplotWizardry_HandsOn.Rmd)

```
ggplot(penguins, aes(x = bill_length_mm, y = bill_depth_mm)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = body_mass_g), alpha = .6, size = 3.5) + 
  ## custom axes scaling
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 3:6 * 10, limits = c(30, 60)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(12.5, 22.5, by = 2.5), limits = c(12.5, 22.5)) +
  ## custom colors
  scico::scale_color_scico(palette = "bamako", direction = -1) +
  ## custom labels
  labs(
    title = 'Bill Dimensions of Brush-Tailed Penguins (Pygoscelis)',
    subtitle = 'A scatter plot of bill depth versus bill length.',
    caption = 'Data: Gorman, Williams & Fraser (2014) PLoS ONE',
    x = 'Bill Length (mm)', 
    y = 'Bill Depth (mm)',
    color = 'Body mass (g)'
  )
```

When knitted or when run in the R console, I get the error

```
Error in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :    polygon edge not found
```

Any ideas what's going on. I updated some packages, and still see the issue.

#### What I've tried

- The above code works for some users (thanks @RuiBarradas)
- I figured perhaps `grid.Call()` couldn't be found for some reason, so I installed `install.packages("NMF", dependencies = TRUE)`, but that didn't help - the same error persists.

Here is my `SessionInfo()` in case it's of use

```
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS  10.16

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_AU.UTF-8/en_AU.UTF-8/en_AU.UTF-8/C/en_AU.UTF-8/en_AU.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] cluster_2.1.0     rngtools_1.5      pkgmaker_0.32.2   registry_0.5-1    patchwork_1.0.1   magick_2.4.0      ggdist_2.4.0     
 [8] ggforce_0.3.3     ggtext_0.1.1      scico_1.2.0       systemfonts_0.3.2 forcats_0.5.0     stringr_1.4.0     dplyr_1.0.3      
[15] purrr_0.3.4       readr_1.3.1       tidyr_1.1.0       tibble_3.0.3      ggplot2_3.3.1     tidyverse_1.3.0  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] nlme_3.1-148         fs_1.4.1             lubridate_1.7.9      doParallel_1.0.15    RColorBrewer_1.1-2   webshot_0.5.2       
 [7] httr_1.4.1           tools_4.0.2          backports_1.1.7      R6_2.4.1             DBI_1.1.0            colorspace_1.4-1    
[13] withr_2.2.0          tidyselect_1.1.0     downlit_0.2.1        curl_4.3             compiler_4.0.2       cli_2.0.2           
[19] rvest_0.3.5          xml2_1.3.2           labeling_0.3         scales_1.1.1         digest_0.6.25        rmarkdown_2.7       
[25] svglite_1.2.3.2      pkgconfig_2.0.3      htmltools_0.5.0      dbplyr_1.4.4         highr_0.8            rlang_0.4.10        
[31] readxl_1.3.1         rstudioapi_0.11      farver_2.0.3         generics_0.0.2       jsonlite_1.7.0       distill_1.2         
[37] distributional_0.2.2 magrittr_1.5         kableExtra_1.3.4     Rcpp_1.0.5           munsell_0.5.0        fansi_0.4.1         
[43] gdtools_0.2.2        lifecycle_0.2.0      stringi_1.4.6        yaml_2.2.1           MASS_7.3-51.6        plyr_1.8.6          
[49] grid_4.0.2           blob_1.2.1           parallel_4.0.2       crayon_1.3.4         lattice_0.20-41      haven_2.3.1         
[55] gridtext_0.1.4       hms_0.5.3            knitr_1.30           pillar_1.4.6         reshape2_1.4.4       codetools_0.2-16    
[61] reprex_0.3.0         glue_1.4.1           evaluate_0.14        rcartocolor_2.0.0    modelr_0.1.8         foreach_1.5.0       
[67] vctrs_0.3.6          tweenr_1.0.2         cellranger_1.1.0     gtable_0.3.0         polyclip_1.10-0      assertthat_0.2.1    
[73] gridBase_0.4-7       xfun_0.22            xtable_1.8-4         broom_0.5.6          viridisLite_0.3.0    iterators_1.0.12    
[79] ellipsis_0.3.1
```

Comment: @ruibarradas I suggest removing the r-markdown tag, since the error is identical when run in console

Comment: OK, that is even in the question. Apologies for not having noticed it.

Comment: @RuiBarradas no problems, appreciate the intent :)

Comment: In R 4.0.5, RStudio Version 1.4.1103, Ubuntu 20.04, I cannot reproduce the error, the posted code worked.

Comment: @RuiBarradas thanks for trying. I did some googling of grid.Call() (I originally thought it interfaced with c/c++ code, but now I'm thinking R simply couldn't find that function because NMF wasn't installed (I hadn't heard of NMF until now). I'm installing NMF with dependencies now, hopefully that's all that was wrong. Either way, I'll update with what  I find. Since it works for you, that indicates there's something wrong that unique to my circumstances

Comment: @RuiBarradas unfortunately installing NMF didn't help, I'll try updating to R 4.0.5

Comment: I don't have package NMF installed and I don't see what it has to do with the question's code. Try restarting your R session, if this doesn't work, do you have a .RData file in you home directory? The .RData file saves the last session when you exit R and it is loaded when a new session starts.

Comment: @RuiBarradas the error message says the problem is in `grid.Call`, and googling `grid.Call` gives https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/NMF/versions/0.17/topics/grid.Call.graphics

Comment: @RuiBarradas I might have some deeper issues, since `install.packages("V8")` doesn't even succeed. I suspect something is wrong/misconfigured in my OS.

Comment: Write a file with your code and from the command line run `Rscript --vanilla <filename.R>`. If the problem still persists then reinstall R, if not, it's something else, maybe a problem with RStudio.

Comment: Don't forget to start the script by loading `library(ggplot2)` and the dataset, `data(penguins, package = "palmerpenguins")`.